# Using JWT stored in HTTPonly & secure cookie: Vulnerable to CSRF. but not to XSS?

Tags: cookies, xss

I understood webstorage is vulnerable to xss

And Cookie to CSRF also makes sense

What makes me puzzled is that it seems like implicitly said that cookie is not vulnerable to xss, but isn't it also vulnerable to xss?

If I can run a script on other's browser, I think I might be able to just send request to server & get important data cause browser automatically attach cookies & I dont' need to do anything to get authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

If a cookie is set with the `httpOnly` flag, it cannot be accessed from Javascript (injected js cannot read or write such cookies), so it is not possible to steal the cookie value if it's `httpOnly`. This is very relevant for a session cookie. In this case, this cookie is not affected by XSS. Note that this is solely because of the `httpOnly` flag - cookies without `httpOnly` *are* affected by XSS, because they are accessible to Javascript.

Any cookie (regardless of flags*) will still be sent with any request to the server it was received from, but that is the realm of csrf, actually, it is the fundamental problem in csrf. If anybody (from any website) makes a request to a server, any cookie for that server will be sent, and the attacker can exploit csrf if there is no protection. That's why you need protection against csrf if you have cookie-based authentication.

Also note that if the page is vulnerable to XSS, than any csrf protection is useless, because xss can be used to read the token, wherever it is stored.

*Sidenote: the new SameSite cookie flag changes this, but that is only supported by Chrome.

Comment: thank you so much!

I thought if csrf is done in 'samesite', it would be classified to xss because it's not 'cross-site'

but it might seem more similiar to csrf because it exploits same defect